# What is a separable distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, monte-carlo

In a text I am using, there is a constant echo of *separable distribution*. I haven't been able to find more information of this on any resources.

Would someone kindly explain to me its intuitive idea and provide an analogy of what a separable and non - separable distribution is?

I am guessing *separable* is used to mean *independent* but I cannot be sure.

**Context**: on the topic of metropolis method in high dimensions

*Consider the case of a target distribution that is an N - dimension Gaussian, and a proposal distribution that is a spherical Gaussian of standard deviation $\epsilon$ in each direction. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the target distribution is a separable distribution aligned with the axes ${x_{n}}$, and that ...*

Comment: Can you give an example of the context? Does "product form" possibly work as an interpretation?

Comment: @BrianTung I cannot be sure. I am familiar with "product form" in the context of separable function with regards to analytically - solvable PDEs but not in the context of probability/ Monte Carlo theory. This said, I have provided more context in the OP.

Comment: What is the text (i.e., author and title)?

Comment: @BrianTung https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu//~ee121/sp08/handouts/it.pdf

page 369

Comment: If I had to guess I'd assume this means the components are independent random variables (i.e. the density is a separable function, $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$).

Comment: @Ian: Interestingly, I think there are cases where the RVs are not independent but you still get the product form.

Comment: True, but I was implicitly taking the Gaussian part of the setup into account.